# How to Split Dataset in R with respect to a column containing NA or it consists a value

Tags: r

I have a got 76 variables and here my Y is `SalePrice`, I had combined the train and test data to shape the variables now I want to split it again.

```r
project_train_2 <- filter(project_final, project_final$SalePrice == 'NA')

Pro_train <- createDataPartition(project_final, project_final[project_train_2, ])
```

Here `project_final` is the combined `Train` and test data, which I want to split with respect to the `SalePrice` column either having `NA` or is having a value.
Those having values have to be in `Train` and the ones not having the test.

I have used the above command to filter data and there by using the CreatedataPartition code to split the data.

Need help on the same.

Comment: I assume you are using `dplyr::filter` (and not `stats::filter`, for which this will not work); do not use `project_file$` inside of it, just do `filter(project_final, SalePrice == 'NA')`. Furthermore, is it the literal string `"NA"` or is it R's `NA`, in which case you'd want `filter(project_final, is.na(SalePrice))`.

Comment: filter(project_final, is.na(SalePrice)), thanks this worked.

Comment: what will be the command to filter SalePrice which has vallues, I am using the following command however it also gets all the rows with NA as well.         
project_train_2= filter(project_final,is.integer(SalePrice))

Comment: You misunderstand `data.frame`s: everything in a column is the same *class*, so even the `NA`s in that column will be marked as integer. Do you want `filter(project_final, !is.na(SalePrice))`, returning all rows that do not have an `NA` price?

Comment: Background: there are five types of `NA`, though they are always printed as the basic `NA`. There are also: `NA_integer_` (what you have, likely), `NA_real_` (is `numeric`), `NA_complex_`, and `NA_character_`. The basic `NA` that is not yet associated with strings or numbers will be a `logical`, so `is.logical(NA)` is true, not `is.logical(c(1,NA))`, instead `is.numeric(c(1,NA))`. The reason is that everything in a vector *must* be the same class (`logical`, `integer`, `numeric`, `character`); each column in a (normal) `data.frame` is a vector internally, so shares the same-class requirement.

Comment: Thanks filter(project_final, !is.na(SalePrice)., this works. 
Thanks r2evans, Is there any course which will help me clear the concepts of the data.frames.

Comment: You could Google "r tutorial data structures" and find quite a few. I'd start with Hadley's [Advanced R - Data Structures] (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).